# function returning an object in python

Tags: python, oop, function

Is it possible in python to define a function `def my_func()` which creates and returns an object of some user-defined class, so that one can call attributes of this object as `my_func().attr`? I am trying to create an operator which accept an object and depending on its attributes generates another object.

Comment: You can assign attributes to function objects.

Comment: I have already user-defined class, which I would like to use in order to generate an instance

Comment: It's impossible to define a function that does not allow this. Even with the definition `def f(): return` you can do `foo().__init__` to get the `NoneType` initializer.

Comment: @larsmans In this case, which function __init__ does it call, the one belonging to the function class or the one belonging to the user-defined class object of which is returned by the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with whatever class you want, but here's a quick example using `namedtuple`

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
>>> def my_func():
        return Point(1, 9)

>>> my_func().x
1
```

This code is completely useless though

Comment: That is what I need. Can I put Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y') in the body of the function?

Comment: @freude yes if you want, you should really try some of these things too

Comment: Is not Point(1,9) out of scope in the function's body. How could it be visible? You have defined it outside the function

Comment: @freude it's in global scope

Comment: One more question, please. Can I say that the function returns a reference (pointer) to the object in your example? How does python do that?

Comment: @freude no you can't say that, it returns the object itself, not a reference to it, there are no pointers in Python anyway

Comment: @jamylak -- well, in the terminology that a lot of people use with python, it does return a "reference" to the object, but a python reference is not the same thing as a "pointer".

Comment: @mgilson good point my explanation came out wrong